# Python wilcoxon: unequal N

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

Rs `wilcox.test` can take different length vectors, but the wilcoxon from `scipy.stats` cannot: I get an `unequal N` error message.

```
from scipy.stats import wilcoxon
wilcoxon(range(10), range(12))
```

Is there a way to get Rs behavior in Python?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the R docs:

```
Performs one- and two-sample Wilcoxon tests on vectors of data; the latter is also known as ‘Mann-Whitney’ test.
```

So just use

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
mannwhitneyu(range(10), range(12))
# (50.0, 0.26494055917435472)
```

Comment: and `wilcoxon` in scipy is the paired test which requires equal length. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html  That's the problem with tests named after an author who wrote several hypothesis tests.

Comment: Sorry if this is a question for `stats.stackexchange` but can I just always use `mannwhitneyu` over `wilcoxon`?

Comment: That is not prog related. Try stats.stackexchange :)