# difference between wilcox and mannwhitneyu test in python (in case of range difference)

Tags: python, statistics

I need to do a wilcox test between 2 lists with uneven range. The link - [Python wilcoxon: unequal N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33890367/python-wilcoxon-unequal-n?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) suggests to use the following

`from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
mannwhitneyu(range(10), range(12))`

As per my knowledge the hypothesis approach by both tests differ so can we do this in programming or do we have any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test

> In statistics, the Mann–Whitney U test (also called the
>   Mann–Whitney–Wilcoxon (MWW), Wilcoxon rank-sum test, or
>   Wilcoxon–Mann–Whitney test)

If you are talking about Wilcoxon rank-sum test, just apply the `mannwhitneyu` function as stated in your link. They are the same test.